# How to add markdown as a preprocessor to the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, sprockets

I have markdown files in `app/assets/md/*.html.md` which I would like to precompile with `rake assets:precompile`.

How can I set the asset pipeline up so that it will use a markdown parser to produce the expected HTML files?

Also, how can I include these precompiled assets directly within my views, such as:

```html
<div>
  <%= yield asset("my_markdown_fragment.html") %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since found the solution. Here is what I did:

1. Add `rdiscount` to the `Gemfile` ([`rdiscount`](https://github.com/davidfstr/rdiscount/) is a Markdown processor for Ruby):

   ```
   gem 'rdiscount'
   ```
2. Create the file `lib/markdown_preprocessor.rb` with these contents:

   ```
   require 'rdiscount'

   class MarkdownPreprocessor < Sprockets::Processor
     def evaluate(context, locals)
       RDiscount.new(begin;data;end).to_html
     end
   end
   ```
3. Add the `MarkdownPreprocessor` to the asset pipeline in the `config/initializers/sprockets.rb` file (create this file if it does not exist) like this:

   ```
   require 'markdown_preprocessor'

   Rails.application.assets.register_engine('.md', MarkdownPreprocessor)
   ```
4. Add the following line to the `config/initializers/assets.rb` file:

   ```
   Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'md')
   ```

Configuration is done now. Here are some other guides and tips:

- Place your Markdown files into the `app/assets/md/` folder.
- The extension of your files end with `.md`, but I suggest `.html.md` (since the result is an HTML file).
- You can insert `<%= ruby %>` into your Markdown files when you add the `.erb` extension. For example, try creating this file `app/assets/md/hello.html.md.erb` with the following contents:

  ```
  # Hello <%= "_World_ " * 42 %>
  ```
- You can access the resulting HTML content in your views and controllers with:

  ```
  Rails.application.assets[asset_path].to_s.html_safe
  ```

Comment: A good way to get `asset_path` is `Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'md', "#{file_name}.html.md")`. Also you can put step 2 in `lib/assets` if in step 3 you `require 'assets/markdown_preprocessor'`.